# SwiftUI View animation transition not working as expected

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the following app I want to navigate in this order Blue -> Red -> Green. Old views should slide off to the left and new views should come in from the right. Clicking "blue to red" works as expected - Blue animates away to the left and Red comes in from the right. But "red to green" doesn't work as expected. Red goes off to the right as Green comes in from the right. Why?

```
@main
struct RouterAnimationApp: App {
    
    @ObservedObject var router = Router.shared
    @State private var isMovingForward: Bool = true

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    switch(router.currentScreen) {
                    case .red:
                        RedView()
                            .transition(Router.shared.navForward ? .forwardTransition : .backTransition)

                    case .blue:
                        BlueView()
                            .transition(Router.shared.navForward ? .forwardTransition : .backTransition)
                        
                    case .green:
                        GreenView()
                            .transition(Router.shared.navForward ? .forwardTransition : .backTransition)

                    }
                }
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0), value: router.currentScreen)

                
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        Router.shared.navForward = true
                        Router.shared.goToScreen(screen: .red)
                    }, label: {
                        Text("blue to red")
                    })
                    Button(action: {
                        Router.shared.navForward = true
                        Router.shared.goToScreen(screen: .green)
                    }, label: {
                        Text("red to green")
                    })
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension AnyTransition {       
    static var forwardTransition: AnyTransition {
        .asymmetric(
            insertion: .move(edge: .trailing).combined(with: .opacity),
            removal: .move(edge: .trailing).combined(with: .opacity)
        )
    }
    
    static var backTransition: AnyTransition {
        .asymmetric(
            insertion: .move(edge: .leading).combined(with: .opacity),
            removal: .move(edge: .leading).combined(with: .opacity)
        )
    }
}
```

And the router:

```
enum Screen : Equatable {
    case blue
    case red
    case green
}

class Router: ObservableObject {


public static let shared = Router()

@Published var currentScreen:Screen = .blue
@Published var previousScreen:Screen = .blue

var navForward: Bool = false

func goToScreen(screen: Screen) {
    previousScreen = currentScreen
    currentScreen = screen
}
```

}

Views just look like this:

```
struct BlueView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color(.blue)
    }
}
```

EDIT: I also need to back:

```
Button(action: {
                        Router.shared.navForward = false
                        Router.shared.goToScreen(screen: .red)
                    }, label: {
                        Text("green to red")
                    })
                    Button(action: {
                        Router.shared.navForward = false
                        Router.shared.goToScreen(screen: .blue)
                    }, label: {
                        Text("red to blue")
                    })
```

Comment: My suspicion is that you are running into the problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75806791/560942

Comment: Yeah, very similar. Tried a few things there but still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to [SwiftUI bi-directional move transition moving the wrong way in certain cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75806791/20386264), which was referenced in the first comment, gives a possible explanation for why the problem is happening. It was my answer.

The answer also provides a general-purpose solution for panels that slide in and out.  The solution is suitable for when the panels have a fixed ordering, which seems to be the case here.

Your example can be adapted to use the `PanelPair` that you will find in that answer, with these changes:

- the enum `Screen` needs to implement `Comparable`
- a computed property `asString` could be added to the enum, for convenience
- `Router` can be simplified down to a single published property
- the state variable `isMovingForward` is not needed.

```swift
enum Screen: Equatable, Comparable {
    case blue
    case red
    case green

    var asString: String {
        "\(self)"
    }
}

class Router: ObservableObject {

    public static let shared = Router()

    @Published var currentScreen: Screen = .blue

    func goToScreen(screen: Screen) {
        currentScreen = screen
    }
}

@main
struct RouterAnimationApp: App {

    @ObservedObject var router = Router.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack {

                // The panels
                PanelPair(
                    leftTab: Screen.blue,
                    selectedTab: router.currentScreen,
                    leftContent: { BlueView() },
                    rightContent: {
                        PanelPair(
                            leftTab: Screen.red,
                            selectedTab: router.currentScreen,
                            leftContent: { RedView() },
                            rightContent: { GreenView() }
                        )
                    }
                )
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0), value: router.currentScreen)

                // The buttons
                VStack(spacing: 40) {
                    let firstTarget: Screen = router.currentScreen == .blue ? .red : .blue
                    Button {
                        router.goToScreen(screen: firstTarget)
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(router.currentScreen.asString) to \(firstTarget.asString)")
                    }

                    let secondTarget: Screen = router.currentScreen == .green ? .red : .green
                    Button {
                        router.goToScreen(screen: secondTarget)
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(router.currentScreen.asString) to \(secondTarget.asString)")
                    }
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use your custom transitions, just replace the modifier being used in `PanelPair`:

```swift
ZStack {
    if selectedTab <= leftTab {
        leftContent()
//            .modifier(TransitionLeading())
            .transition(.backTransition)
    } else {
        rightContent()
//            .modifier(TransitionTrailing())
            .transition(.forwardTransition)
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

BTW, if you only need to support iOS 16.0+, you will see from the same answer that your transitions can be simplified to the following:

```swift
extension AnyTransition {
    static var forwardTransition: AnyTransition {
        .move(edge: .trailing).combined(with: .opacity)
    }

    static var backTransition: AnyTransition {
        .move(edge: .leading).combined(with: .opacity)
    }
}
```

If in fact you need to support earlier iOS versions then you might want to adapt the transitions as shown in the other answer.

Comment: Hmm, I appreciate the answer but this doesn't seem scalable to me. In my actual app I have 20-30 screens that can be navigated to from either direction. I can't create logic for every possible scenario. I just need to be able to specify the screen I want to navigate to and if the forward or backward transition animation should be used to present it.